# Data is not render into EJS page

Tags: node.js, sql-server, ejs

I am looking for a solution for my EJS template. I am working on a project and I have completed about 50% of it. Currently I am working on a web page where I have to display the SQL data into EJS web template.

I have posted my coding which is i am working on it.

1. data is receiving from database (I checked with console.log and I posted the Json out put).

I tried all the possible ways to work it out but I did not get the result. It would be great if someone could help me..

Thanks in advance.

```js
/* app.js */

app.get('/data', receiveData);

function receiveData(req, res)
{
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM arduino", function (recordsets, err, ) {

        var data = JSON.stringify(recordsets);

        if (err) {
            httpMsgs.show500(request, res, err);
        }
        else {

             var    Jdata = JSON.parse(data);
           res.render('arduino',{Jdata:Jdata});

            console.log(data);

        }
    });
}
```

```html
/* arduino.ejs */

<html>
<head>
<body>

<div class="page-data">
    <div class="data-table">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">
            <tr>
                <th> - </th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Machine</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Length Time</th>
                <th> Day/Night</th>
                <th>Job Number</th>
            </tr>
            <% if(Jdata.length){

            for(var i = 0;i < Jdata.length;i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=(i+1)%></td>
                <td> </td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].Machine%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].StartTime%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].EndTime%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].LengthTime%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].Day%></td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].ID %></td>
                <td><%=Jdata[i].JobNumber %></td>
            </tr>
            <% }

            }else{ %>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">No Data</td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

```
{"recordsets":[[{"ID":1,"Machine":"TRUMPF 5000","StartTime":"2018-11-01T15:28:51.000Z","EndTime":"2018-11-01T15:52:11.000Z","LengthTime":271,"Day":"Day","JobNumber":null}]]
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to render a template named `arduino` but your `.ejs` template is named as `index.ejs` ???

Comment: hai @DavidR, thanks for your reply. in my folder i have ejs file name arduino. I forgot to modified that part while i am posting here. sorry for the inconvenience.  i am still trying to render the data into my ejs but still I am not able to do it. Thanks again.